# Background picture and loop over qplot, how can I only update the date without reprinting the rest

Tags: r, image, dynamic, background, ggplot2

I wanna use a background png for my plot and change the dataset for the plot points within a loop. Unfortunately print(qplot_object) reprints all and not just changes the data, so the background is plottet again and its slow and flashes :(

I am using `annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf)` for the background and qplot (ggplot does somehow not work, because then the picture is not in the background, but infront of the data). Also the old version with `opts(panel.background=function(...)picture)` does not work anymore.

Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra) # for ebimageGrob
require(png)
require(grid)

img <- readPNG("bla.png")
g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)

mdat <- data.frame(100,100)
colnames(mdat ) <- c("X","Y")

plot_field <- qplot(mdat[,1],mdat[,2], geom="blank") +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 1200),ylim = c(0, 799)) +
  annotation_custom(g, xmin=-Inf, xmax=Inf, ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf) +
  geom_point()+ theme_bw() +
  theme(
   panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
       panel.margin.x = unit(12,"cm"),
       panel.margin.y = unit(7.99,"cm"),
       aspect.ratio = 799/1200
   )       

print(plot_field)

for (i in 1:100){ 
 mdat <- data.frame(100+i*5,100+i)
 colnames(mdat) <- c("X","Y")
 print(plot_field) # this works, but replots all, so its flashing all the time and slow,  
                   #because of the background png (annotation_custom)
}
```

I hope someone has an idea, maybe there is any dynamic plotting class or a canvas to draw in R. The idea of the code is actually to load a soccer field and then run a simulation and update the positions of the players in every time step. Therefore the qlot should not flash all the time, just the players should move, maybe I can deal with separate layers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to stop the flashing is to prevent the screen from updating till all the drawing is done. Try

```
for (i in 1:100){ 
   mdat <- data.frame(100+i*5,100+i)
   colnames(mdat) <- c("X","Y")
   dev.hold()  #pause device update
   print(plot_field)
   dev.flush() #send plot to device
}
```